# Grafana regex for instance name prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I am new to grafana and below is the metric which I am plotting, on Grafana and the regex which I've used is giving what I need but when it is supposed to display it should be something which matches the worker name.
Metric: `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~"[q|u]1lxdwhpl.*"}`

Eg: For `u1lxdwhpl04.company.com` I want the legend to display **worker4**.
The legend has `{{instance}}` right now.

Comment: I think the error is NOT in the regex. This one worked for me: node_cpu_seconds_total{job="gcp_ne_discovery",instance=~"[p|t]rod-platform-.*",mode="idle",network="company"}

Comment: can you post the full line query ?